# Light weight Bug reporting javascript form?

Tags: javascript, php, debugging, bug-reporting

I am knee deep in development for a sports league manager application.  I thought I recalled seeing a web app / JavaScript plugin / process that would let users just click on a 'hovering element' (like 'report a bug' button) on my site and have a bug form slide down / pop up.

I recall seeing something like that.  I want to make it as easy as possible for someone to report a bug as it happens, when it happens, but I just don't want to take the time to code that process. Nor do I want users to have to register somewhere. I jsut want a one way with email optional process.

Anyone use something like that before? Did it work well?

If not, how did you handle bug tracking for web users without having them sign in / register anywhere? I don't want them using a sign in app, I just want some simple form that might let them type out what they were doing, and have it shoot off to me for a fix.

Appreciate the input as I'm trying to keep it simple and focus on the app (this is a non profit thing I'm working on, so can't dedicate too much time for it).

Comment: [Usersnap](https://usersnap.com/?gat=sogd) is a bug reporting widget which integrates with a lot of bug tracking tools and automatically creates bug reports with a screenshot and browser information.

The users don't have to sign in and really can focus on your app!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you want. But there are a bunch of feedback tools out there.

Sitepoint has an article out there

http://blogs.sitepoint.com/customer-feedback-tools/

which discusses the top 10 best customer feedback tools.

Some of them are not for free though.

Hope this helps as a starting point.

Regards

Comment: yes, exactly what I recalled, but I'm hoping for a free one for bug reporting, going to review some of these.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer as it helped me 'find' the webapp I was looking for, but I am unhappy with getsatisfaction due to them being unwilling to make 'anonymous' posting a possibility. Thanks @Jeremy S.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [BugHerd](http://bugherd.com/). It definitely sounds like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep errors in log and get any information you need with using **[debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)** to see which file and code line is causing error. You could also get ref. url, or current url or any other kind of information which you might find useful.

Imagine this;

- You could keep, user IP / logged in user ID
- You could keep, date, ref. url / current url.
- You could keep, which included file and which line caused the error.
- You could create a log file with dates. Such as 04.18.2011.txt easier and organized.
- You could block let's say logs/ folder with .htaccess so it will be private if you want.
- You don't get to push users to send you bug reports.
- Don't forget many visitors are lazy. They will not even want to do few clicks. This way you will keep track of each errors in your system without having a need to wait for someone to report it.

If you still would like users to post some data it is a different story (for example clicked link (or anything on the page) didn't return the value (or did what user wanted) as expected. If you want report of this then you could keep store them as well as just simply mail yourself which would save you time for coding.

If you need help with Javascript part, I could help you with it since I worked on something similar on my own project.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the offer, but I specifically want something like 'getsatisfaction' except I can't stand 'getsatisfaction' because they force the user to sign in with openid, and I just want bug reports.  My users for this app know its beta / active development, and are using the app and helping squash bugs. But I just want an easy to use bug reporting feature, not mail, not additional server side logging.